# Crop & Aspect Ratio Icons

Tags: field

This is a very loosely associated question but looking at the plugin page for Pimp My Matrix, they depict icons for Crop Position, and Crop Aspect Ratio:

[image: Crop position & aspect ratio icons]

Are these custom fields from somewhere or is it possible somehow to add your own icons for something which looks to be essentially a radio button or select type of field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the [Button Box](http://plugins.supercooldesign.co.uk/plugin/button-box) plugin, also from the team who developed Pimp My Matrix.

Comment: Ah, I think you're right. It looks to be the 'Button Box - Buttons' field where you can upload your own icons. Nice spot. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Ian No problem! I haven't used the plugin before but it definitely looks useful.